# form error codeigniter ajax php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello I am trying to send mail with ajax and codeigniter. It all works fine but the form error doesn't word, if someone has an idea thx !

```
<script>
$(function() {
$('#mail').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var form_data = {
   name: $('#name').val(),
   email: $('#email').val(),
   message: $('#message').val()
  };
  $.ajax({

        url : '<?php echo base_url('contact/send_email'); ?>',
        data : form_data,
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'JSON',
        success: function(result) {

            if(result.valid == 1)
            {
                $('#mail').prepend('<div id="success" class="alert alert-success">Success</div>');
                $('#success').fadeOut(5000);
            }
            else
            { 
                $('#mail').prepend('<div id="error" class="alert alert-danger">Error</div>');
                $('#error').fadeOut(5000);
            }
        }
    })
});
});
</script>
```

and here my controler:

```
        public function send_email() {

            $result = array();

            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div id="error">', '</div>');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Name','trim|required|xss_clean');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email Address','trim|required|xss_clean');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('message','Message','trim|required|xss_clean');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

                $result['valid'] = 0;
                $data['success'] = '';
                $this->lang->load('header');
                //$this->lang->load('contact');
                $this->lang->load('footer');
                $this->load->view('includes/header', array('app_name' => 'contact', 'csrf_token_name' => $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(), 'csrf_hash' => $this->security->get_csrf_hash()));
                $this->load->view('contact', $data);
                $this->load->view('includes/footer');

            }
            else
            {

                $this->lang->load('header');
                //$this->lang->load('contact');
                $this->lang->load('footer');
                $this->load->view('includes/header', array('app_name' => 'contact', 'csrf_token_name' => $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(), 'csrf_hash' => $this->security->get_csrf_hash()));
                $this->load->view('contact', $data);
                $this->load->view('includes/footer');

                $result['valid'] = 1;
                $data['success'] = 'Email envoyer avec succés';

                $this->load->library('form_validation');
                $this->load->library('email');
                $this->email->from($this->input->post('email'), $this->input->post('name'));
                $this->email->to('lauriaweb@gmail.com');
                $this->email->subject('Message de PoP-Stream');
                $this->email->message($this->input->post('message'));
                $this->email->send();

            }
            die(json_encode($result));
        }
    }
```

i don't understand how to make for error, im lost ^^

thx in advance !

Comment: For one, please separate your two code listings (I can't commit an edit under 6 characters). Secondly, what is the specific error you are getting? What are you expecting to see? That's quite a bit of code to browse through on a whim.

Comment: CI validation is serverside.. so adding validation inside a ajax called function does not work... use client side validation like jquery validation before the form is submit and ajax is called..

Answer (score 0):

You are only marking delimiters in your code

```
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div id="error">', '</div>');
```

This will not show the errors but only wrap them with the div of id 'error'. To show them you will have to do add the below to your view

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
```

Other ways in which you can achieve the same is mentioned below.

```
<?php echo validation_errors('<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>
```

Otherwise you would not get be able to see the validation errors. You can also show individual errors as

```
<?php echo form_error('field name', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>
```

Read more here

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html